# Jordan normal form and spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

In [this post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/11/math-246a-notes-4-singularities-of-holomorphic-functions/) by Terence Tao (exercise 28, point vi), he proves the following theorem (called *spectral decomposition*):

**Theorem:**
Let $A$ be a complex square matrix. Then $A$ can be written as

$A=\sum P_j(\lambda_j I+N_j)P_j$

Where $P_j$ are matrices such that $P_j P_l=0$, $P_j^2=P_j$ and $P_1+\dots +P_k=I$
and $N_j$ is a nilpoten matrix of order $\text{mult}(\lambda_j)$ ($\lambda_j$ is the $j$-th eigenvalue)

This theorem seems really connected with the Jordan form of a matrix, although I am not able to prove that: It is clear that the J.F. implies the spectral decomposition, while the opposite is not so easy: I tried to prove it on a canonical basis in order to generalize it after but I didn't get anywhere.

**Question**:

Is the J.F. actually a consequence of the spectral decomposition? If so, how to prove it?

Comment: You want to replace $n$ by $k$ (the number of different eigenvalues) in $P_1+\cdots+P_n=I$, these are the projections onto the generalized eigenspaces. Furthermore it is not true that $P_j P_l = \delta_{jl} I$, instead we have $P_j P_l = \delta_{jl} P_j$, that is, $P_j^2 = P_j$.

Comment: @Christoph Fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This almost implies the Jordan canonical form. What is missing is the normal form of nilpotent matrices. That is, $N_j$ is similar to a block diagonal matrix with blocks of the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&\ldots &0\\0&0&1&\ldots &0\\\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\0&0&0&\ldots &1\\0&0&0&\ldots &0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This change of basis gives a Jordan basis on each generalized eigenspace, which are the images of the $P_j$.

Comment: How could I prove this special case of J.F.?

Comment: Take any proof of the Jordan form and apply it to the case of nilpotent matrices ;-)